# How do we handle service accounts after Exchange Basic Auth is retired?

Tags: imap, exchange-basicauth

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers/

Our organization is finding this announcement somewhat problematic!  We use an IMAP library extensively to read various service based email accounts in o365.  Any guidance on how to address this would be greatly appreciated.

Note, we have many console apps written in .NET (4.8) that run on a server based fired by many scheduled tasks. I understand we'd need to somehow register our "application" (I'm assuming that can be a generic one for our company), but we cannot involve any "user" interaction. These are utility apps. Glancing at the existing sample code for OAuth, they all seem to involve popping up a browser window to get someone to interact with "asking permission" which is exactly what we need to *avoid*.

We've used IMAP all this time to simply read and parse service based email accounts. I'm not sure I understand why IMAP over a secure connection is "less secure" than a more complex solution. Why take the option away?

On the other hand, the Microsoft Graph API looks significantly more complicated and appears to be OAuth based which, again, seems to involve quite a bit of authentication complexity.

Most REST APIs we've interacted w/ in other .NET console apps use a simple set of API "keys." Why not offer that at least?

As I say, we're looking for a way to write some process that run programmatically to automate a number of operations related to certain mailboxes. IMAP has worked like a charm so far, so we're looking for direct guidance on what to migrate to.

Answer (score 0):

We understand your concerns. While a secure IMAP connection protects the data that's being transported, Basic Authentication exposes your Exchange Online accounts to attack techniques like phishing or brute forcing.

The primary objective of this change is to protect our customers from these threats. In addition, Modern Auth enables admin visibility into app access and enables fine-grained control of these apps.

To answer your question on implementation guidance, there is an existing approach in Graph to achieve exactly what you're looking to do. It's called "OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow". You can read more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

<sub>(Disclosure - I'm a Senior PM at Microsoft)</sub>